# Complex "Contains" string comparison

Tags: c#, string-comparison

I'm developing a C# 4.5 app and I need a function to return true for the following comparison:

> "bla LéOnAr d/o bla".ComplexContains("leonardo")

In other words, I need `string.Compare(str1, str2, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, CompareOptions.IgnoreCase | CompareOptions.IgnoreSymbols | CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace)` to also check for "contains!

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You could use an appropriate `CompareInfo` and then [`CompareInfo.IndexOf(string, string, CompareOptions)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b7zs7dcf.aspx) and check the result against -1. Sample:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var compareInfo = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.CompareInfo;
        var options = CompareOptions.IgnoreCase | 
            CompareOptions.IgnoreSymbols |
            CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace;

        var haystack = "bla Lé OnAr d/o bla";
        var needle = "leonardo";

        var index = compareInfo.IndexOf(haystack, needle, options);
        Console.WriteLine(index); // 4
    }
}
```

Or in method form:

```
private static bool ComplexContains(string source, string value)
{
    var index = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.CompareInfo.IndexOf
        (source, value, CompareOptions.IgnoreCase | 
         CompareOptions.IgnoreSymbols | CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace);
    return index != -1;
}
```

Comment: +1 quick question though... how well EF5 transforms this to TSql? im using LINQ here...

Comment: @Leonardo: I very much doubt that it handles that at all - I wouldn't expect it to. (In future, please give *crucial* details like this in the original question.)

Comment: @JonSkeet it's not so crucial... fyi it does work after all... except that the comparison is done a application server... the result sql is almost a "select * from table..."

Comment: @Leonardo: That suggests you're not actually using that on an `IQueryable<T>` - but if you *did* try doing it on a real queryable type, I'd expect it to fail at execution time. It really is a crucial piece of information - it's like asking about C# and then saying you're actually running Java. *Lots* of stuff which works locally won't work via LINQ.

Comment: The method is perfect . Works a treat.

Comment: This code returns -1 for me, therefore I don't think it's completely accent insensitive. (environment: Xamarin Forms)

Comment: @adamsfamily: I suspect that may well be more about the Xamarin implementation than about the expected behavior.