# C#: what's the equivalent of SQL "LIKE" feature?

Tags: c#

My example code:

```
public static bool StringSearchHit(string keyWord, params string[] targetArray)
{
    foreach (string targetItem in targetArray)
    {
        if (targetItem.IndexOf(keyWord, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The problem I have: the `LIKE` operator in SQL is not just `string.Contain()` or `string.IndexOf()`, there are "culture character similarity" in it (I don't know how to call it).

Example: when I search using `LIKE '%pokemon%'`, the "Pokémon" will also be included. The character "é" will be considered as similar to "e".

Same for some German characters. The special characters "ä ö ü" will also be considered "like" "a o u" in SQL.

My goal: when the `keyWord` is "aou", and one of the `targetArray` has "äöü", it will also return `true`.

Is there any equivalent of this in c#?

**Edit**: thanks for pointing out about another post:

[Ignoring accented letters in string comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359827/ignoring-accented-letters-in-string-comparison)

That is the correct direction, but in another issue, it's "compare", not "contain". How to do similar thing in "string.Contain"?

**Edit 2**: Thanks for the correct answer:

[Complex "Contains" string comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15178922/complex-contains-string-comparison)

Tried this solution, "Pokémon" can be searched using "Pokemon", and "Æon Flux" can be searched using "aeon".

Case close and marked as duplicate.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835790/how-to-do-sql-like-in-linq. In particular this answer is good (uses `SqlMethods.Like()`): https://stackoverflow.com/a/3045735/1447389

Comment: @GSerg Thanks, but I still can't find the answer in the other post. `RemoveAccents` looks good but I don't know which target accent the string has. I can't just use "iso-8859-8" hardcoded.

Comment: Ah, it's about `Contains`, my bad. Possible duplicate of [Complex “Contains” string comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15178922/11683)

Comment: Try Contains() method

Comment: @Soleil `SqlMethods.Like` is for building an SQL query with a C# lambda. There is no SQL context here, the source data is given as a C# string array.

Comment: @Soleil , not a duplicate, GSerg was closer. Please read problem better.

Comment: @GSerg Thanks, your second duplicate suggestion really solves my problem. How do I mark this as duplicate with your second post link?