# How can I do String.StartsWith ignoring diacritics/accents/tildes?

Tags: c#

Title pretty much explains itself, but let's say I have this:

```
string str1 = "microondas";
string str2 = "micrómetro";
bool comparison1 = str1.StartsWith("micro", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
bool comparison2 = str2.StartsWith("micro", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

However, comparison2 will return false. Is there an easy way to make it so it ignores diacritics, accents and tildes (so ó becomes o, ñ becomes n)? Bonus if it's also case insensitive.

I know there's CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace which does what I want, but I haven't found a way to implement it in StartsWith.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Well, 'ó' and 'o' are two different characters

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ignoring accented letters in string comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359827/ignoring-accented-letters-in-string-comparison)

Comment: @MasoudKeshavarz String.Compare cannot answer whether it StartsWith something, and String.IndexOf does not have the required overload.

Comment: @GSerg I just meant that PO could use provided `RemoveDiacritics` function from the link. Please see my answer.

Comment: `Those do NOT answer my question at all!` - You clearly haven't looked at the duplicate. The very first line of the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15178962/11683) goes, *You could use an appropriate CompareInfo and then CompareInfo.IndexOf(string, string, CompareOptions) and check the result against -1*. In your case, you need to check the result against 0. IndexOf of zero means it starts with the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try utilizing the `System.Globalization.CompareInfo.IsPrefix` method, which accepts a `CompareOptions` enum. See the [docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.compareinfo.isprefix?view=netcore-3.1).

Besides this, you can try to manually implement it for youself based on for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/249126/1323504), which deals with removing diacritics from a string.

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked perfectly. I ended up using CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace | CompareOptions.IgnoreCase and did exactly what I wanted!